# Evaluating limit without L'Hospital's

Tags: limits

I would like to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}$$ It can be done with L'Hospital, but I would like to know if it is possible to do so without L'Hospital. I tried multiplying through by the conjugate of the denominator, which leads me to $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x(1+\cos(x))}{\sin(x)}$$ which is not very helpful, because it is still $0/0$. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: $$\dfrac x{\sin x}2(1+\cos(x))$$

Comment: I am amazed to see how most answers so far focus on the half-angle transformation, which is unnecessary. Why don't you guys read the question ?

Comment: You almost reached there. Why stop at the finish line?

Answer (score 3):

From the later form you can use $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$ directly with the product rule to show that the limit is $4$. This identity can be proven without L'Hopital so it's valid to use it. A lot of limits involving trigonometric functions can be solved this way

Answer (score 1):

This is a good opportunity to use power series: near $0$, we have $$\sin x=x-\frac{x^3}{6}+\cdots\quad\text{and}\quad\cos x = 1-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$ so $$2x\sin x=2x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\cdots\quad\text{and}\quad 1-\cos x = \frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots$$

where the dots represent terms of higher degree. It follows that

$$\frac{2x\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}
=
\frac{2x^2-\frac{x^4}{3}+\cdots}{\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^4}{4!}+\cdots}
=
\frac{2-\frac{x^2}{3}+\cdots}{\frac{1}{2}-\frac{x^2}{4!}+\cdots}
$$

By continuity of the sum of power series, we obtain

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{2x\sin(x)}{1-\cos(x)}=\frac{2}{1/2}=4$$

Note: because of the term-by-term differentiation formula for power series, the fact that the valuation of the power series is $2$ implies that we can get the limit by using L'Hospital's Rule **twice**.

Answer (score 0):

Use *equivalents*: it is  standard that  $\:\sin x\sim_0 x\:$ and $\:1-\cos x\sim_0\frac{x^2}2$. Therefore
$$\frac{2x\sin x}{1-\cos x}\sim_0\cdots$$

Answer (score -1):

**Hint**

$$1-\cos(x)=2\sin^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right),$$
and $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=1.$$

Comment: It is always worth mentioning that the limit of $\frac{\sin x}x$ may *look* like one should apply l'Hôpital or the definition of $\sin'$, but this is always one of those limits that one must have shown ab ovo in one's early days.